# Redirect two levels out

Tags: php, redirect

I'm looking for a way to redirect out to my root page. Want to redirect

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2.*$ index.php?page=folder1_folder2 [NC]
```

In the web browser this looks something like

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2
```

UPDATE:
Forgot to add that I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([folder1/]+)/([folder2/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1_$2 [NC,R=301]
```

but for some reason it alters the url to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=folder1_folder2
```

Comment: Something like this? `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1_$2`

Comment: @still_learning sorry forgot to add that I tried that already. I Tried this: `RewriteRule ^([folder1/]+)/([folder2/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1_$2 [NC,R=301]` but for some reason it alters the url to http://www.example.com/index.php?page=college_main

Comment: Please post the complete rule set.it seems to be working correctly according to the given rule.are you trying to _map_ instead of redirect? please include a sample input and desired final url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this worked for me:

```
RewriteRule ^([folder1/]+)/([folder2/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1_$2 [NC,QSA]
```